# Callback in IdentityServer3, with current ASP.NET Identity Session ID available to access

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I am implementing a Single Sign On (SSO) solution using IdentityServer3. I have  ASP.NET 4.5.2 (MVC) application that hosts IdenitityServer. I have requirement to track all signed in users and store their activity in a database. That is at sign in time in my custom Identity Server, I need to record the issued ASP.NET Identitiy Session ID along with the user's Id. Then, when one of the client applications is used, it sends a signal to my custom Identitiy Server. The signal contains that ASP.NET identity Session. This signal is used to detect activity across all clients, and hence my custom Identitiy Server can extend the validity of the user's session. Note that this logic is needed in case the user decides to sign in to another client.

The technical challenge I face now is to find a place in Identity Server, that happens just after local sign in, and contains the current ASP.NET Identitiy session id.

So far I have found the following function in the custom **[IUserService](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html)** that I could implement:

```
    // Summary:
    //     This method is called prior to the user
    //     being issued a login cookie for IdentityServer.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   context:
    //     The context.
    public virtual Task PostAuthenticateAsync(PostAuthenticationContext context);
```

In my custom IUserService, I have injected the IOwinContext, but as the comment states, this function is invoked **before** the user gets IdentityServer cookie issued.

I have browsed IdentityServer3's [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/), and could not find a single place, where on can plug custom code in the pipeline, that executes after a full sign in has happened. I need such place, so that I can write to my database that a new user is currently signed in, and which ASP.NET identitiy session id belongs to him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the IEventService -- this provides you with strongly-typed, activity related notifications of activity in IdentityServer. https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/events.html

Comment: The only event that contains the session ID is the token issued event. Is that guaranteed to always contain the session?
        if (evt.Name == "Identity token issued" && evt.Details is TokenIssuedDetailsBase)
        {}

Comment: If you need an enhancement so the session id in other events, then open an issue on the github issue tracker.

Comment: It currently works, but I was just wondering if that will always be the case. I don't want to get suprizes in the future. Thanks for the answer! :)